# Javascript in Qualtrics: Referencing the displayed order of a choice

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

For a question, I have 4 choices (alpha, beta, gamma, delta) displayed in random order through choice randomization. I want the displayed order of these choices to be captured in embedded data fields, to be used later in the survey (to study how order in which choices are displayed affects recall, for example). For instance, if the choices were displayed in the order

beta gamma alpha delta

I want embedded data fields pos_beta = 1, pos_gamma = 2, pos_alpha=3 and pos_delta=4.

If they were displayed

gamma alpha beta delta

I want embedded data fields pos_gamma = 1, pos_alpha = 2, etc

Easiest way to implement this? (Also, could the answer be generic enough to capture if the choices had random text around the keywords - "blah blah gamma blah blah" etc?)

I guess I have to loop through each choice using some version of:

```
jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" [type=radio]").each(function(i) {
}
```

and within the loop check sequentially if "alpha", "beta" etc is contained in the choice text, and then assign i to the corresponding embedded data field. Is this approach correct, and if yes, how do I check if a specific substring is contained in the choice text?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are the embedded data fields stored? On the option, the select, or the form itself? Do you have sample HTML markup?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl , I really do not understand what that means. I initialized the embedded fields at the beginning of the survey itself (much before this question) so I guess they are stored at the survey level? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  var qobj = this;
  jQuery(this.questionContainer).find("[choiceid]").each(function(i) {
    var cid = jQuery(this).attr("choiceid");
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("pos_"+qobj.getChoiceVariableName(cid),i+1);
  });
});
```

You can decouple variable names from the displayed choice labels by setting them using 'Recode Values'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add data attributes to `<option>` elements, based on their original potion in the source array, you can use `indexOf` to find the original index.

```js
const clearOptions = (selectEl) => {
  while (selectEl.options.length > 0) selectEl.remove(0);
};

const shuffleArr = (arr) => {
  const res = [], copy = [...arr];
  while (copy.length > 0) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    res.push(copy[index]);
    copy.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return res;
};

const positions = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta'];

const populateSelect = (selectEl, choices) => {
  clearOptions(selectEl);
  const initialOption = new Option('-- Select an answer --', '');
  initialOption.disabled = true;
  initialOption.selected = true;
  selectEl.add(initialOption);
  shuffleArr(choices).forEach((choice, index) => {
    let
      answerIndex = choices.indexOf(choice),
      option = new Option(`${String.fromCharCode(index + 65)}) ${choice}`, choice);
    option.setAttribute(`data-pos-${positions[answerIndex]}`, index + 1);
    selectEl.add(option);
  });
};

const answerSelect = document.querySelector('select[name="answer"]');

const data = {
  choices: ['3.1415...', '2.7182...', '1.6180...', '6.2831...'],
  answer: '3.1415...'
};

const setup = () => {
  populateSelect(answerSelect, data.choices);
};

const submitAnswer = (e, form) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const answer = form.elements.answer.value;
  console.log(answer === data.answer ? 'Correct!' : 'Incorrect');
  setup();
};

setup();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 3rem !important; }
```

```html
<h1>Question 1</h1>
<p>What is the closest value to the constant PI?</p>
<form onsubmit="submitAnswer(event, this)" autocomplete="off">
  <select id="answer" name="answer" class="random" required></select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The following code above will construct something similar to below:

```html
<form onsubmit="submitAnswer(event, this)" autocomplete="off">
  <select id="answer" name="answer" class="random" required="">
    <option value="" disabled="">-- Select an answer --</option>
    <option value="1.6180..." data-pos-gamma="1">A) 1.6180...</option>
    <option value="2.7182..." data-pos-beta="2">B) 2.7182...</option>
    <option value="3.1415..." data-pos-alpha="3">C) 3.1415...</option>
    <option value="6.2831..." data-pos-delta="4">D) 6.2831...</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I am really sorry - you have provided a wonderfully detailed answer - but it went over my head. My knowledge of qualtrics and js is v limited. To explain my survey, I have  embedded data fields pos_alpha, pos_beta etc (initialiazed to 0) at the beginning of the survey. I then have a q which has choices alpha, beta, etc (These are text, not variables). The order of these choices have been randomized using the choice randomizer in qualtrics. So I do not know what order they were displayed to the respondent, but I want to capture that order in the embedded fields pos_alpha etc, ..(contd)

Comment: .(contd)..to be used later in the survey. If not too much to ask, could you help me with how to implement this?   Alternatively,  I think your code is doing the randomization as well. Could you just give me some pointers on what the different sections of your code are doing so that I can understand and try to modify for my requirements? Thanks again and sorry for my ineptitude!

Comment: To be clear, I do not want to randomize the choices in the code itself (The choices are randomized in a separate question using the choice randomizer in qualtrics and are carried forward to this question). I just want the code to pick up the order in which the choices were displayed, if possible? Thanks again!